# $p$-divisibility of consecutive Bernoulli numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, bernoulli-numbers

I have asked the same question in MathStackExchange. ([Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4719571/p-divisibility-of-consecutive-bernoulli-numbers))

Let $B_n$ be $n$-th Bernoulli number. We will write $p \mid B_n$ if prime $p$ divides the numerator of $B_n$.

Now $p = 587$, we can show $p \mid B_{90}$ and $p \mid B_{92}$ (I found it using computer). So, there exists two consecutive non-zero Bernoulli numbers divisible by same prime.

**Question :** What is the maximum length of a sequence of consecutive non-zero Bernoulli numbers divisible by a sufficiently large prime $p$?

I have no idea how to progress. I'm looking for some ideas or some references. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Item 14 in https://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~davidharvey/index.php?page=research has a lot of cases when $p<n-1$. I would start by searching through this.